# Ubuntu 14.04 prevent screen turning off in lock screen

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

Every time when I am in lock screen, the screen will automatically turn off. I have tried to change the setting in `Brightness and lock` turn screen off when inactive to `never`. It will not turn off my screen when I am logged into the Desktop view but it will still turn off my screen when I am in lock screen.

How to prevent it to turn off the screen in lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

My experience: I tried setting the option **"turn off screen"** to never and **"lock screen"** to 30 seconds, but the computer never locks automatically.

It seems like the time to lock the screen its only after the screen turns off, in that case the **"lock screen"** option should be grayed out when **"turn off screen"** its set to **never**.